# MPAndroidChart Line Graph only shows the first label of the array

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I have a line chart with data and after I calculate the labels and give to the chart, it doesn't show all of them, only the first one.

This happens on both axes.

I can't seem to find the problem. Am I missing something on the chart setUp, or in the data population.

Here how I set the chart up:

```
fun LineChart.init() {
    this.apply {
        ... //other non relevant set up
        with(xAxis) {
            isEnabled = true
            setDrawAxisLine(true)
            axisLineWidth = 0f
            setDrawGridLines(true)
            setDrawLabels(true)
            axisMaximum = Constants.CHART_LABELS_COUNT * 4F
            axisMinimum = 0F
            position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
            granularity = Constants.CHART_LABELS_COUNT.toFloat()
            isGranularityEnabled = true
            enableGridDashedLine(10f, 10f, 10f)
        }
        axisRight.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Here is how I populate the chart with data:

```
with(binding.speedChart) {
    marker = CustomMarkerView(requireContext(), R.layout.custom_marker_view, 0f)
    data = lineData
    animateXY(500, 1000)

    with(axisLeft) {
        setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART)
        axisMaximum = (((maxSpeed / CHART_LABELS_COUNT).toInt() + 1) * CHART_LABELS_COUNT).toFloat()
        axisMinimum = 0F
        granularity = CHART_LABELS_COUNT.toFloat()
        isGranularityEnabled = true
        setDrawGridLines(false)
        isEnabled = true

        setLabelCount(CHART_LABELS_COUNT - 1, true)
        valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(yLabels)
    }
    xAxis.labelCount = CHART_LABELS_COUNT - 1
    xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(xLabels)
    invalidate()
}
```

The chart looks like this:
[image: chart]

As you can see, and I checked with debug, the labels are calculated fine, ex. time intervals [3:01, 6:02, 9:03, 12:04, 13:05], but only the first one shows up

Answer (score 0):

Even though I still don't understand why does this happen, what I did to make a roundabout fix is by implementing a custom `ValueFormatter` and the labels now are showing. I have no idea why it doesn't work with the `IndexAxisValueFormatter`.
So, for anyone wondering, try to implement the custom `ValueFormatter` and override its method to get the label depending on value.

Comment: The reason it only shows the first entry is that `IndexAxisValueFormatter` literally just converts the x value to an integer and uses it to look up that index in the labels array. So if the x value is "0" it will get `labels[0]` and if the next x value where a label is drawn is "25" it will get `labels[25]` (or return a blank string if there aren't 25 entries). If your x-values are not nice integer spacing you have to make a custom `ValueFormatter`.

Comment: You can see what it does [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/IndexAxisValueFormatter.java)